# Новое fxml окно

Tags: javafx, tableview, fxml

Имеется проект javafx с такой структурой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В main.fxml имеется таблица, при двойном клике на любую из ее строк должно открываться окно details.fxml.
C двойным кликом разобрался, но окно не создается, не распознает директорию.
Пробовал так:

```
Parent root1 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/views/details.fxml"));
```

и так:

```
Parent root1 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("views/details.fxml"));
```

и еще все остальные комбинации с шагом в одну папку со слешем и без + через url + через полный путь.

В Main-е, при запуске основного окна, работает такое:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("views/main.fxml"));
```

exception:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
```

Answer (score 1):

`getClass().getResource` ссылается на ту же папку, в которой находится вызываемый класс, в данном случае `MainController`, он находится в `controllers`, и в этой папке программа ищет `views` и не находит. Вам надо либо подниматься на уровень выше, либо использовать другую отправную точку.
например заменить `this.getClass().getResource` на `Main.class.getResource`